# How to set up a specific reject message for a HTML number input element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I have a loop of html forms `<input type="number">`, which are basically simple algebra calculations for certain people to fill in. I set the correct answer by limiting both the max and min accepted number to the same number. However, in this way, if the participant gives a wrong answer, the reject message would be something like this: "values must be greater than or equal to ...". It is technically correct but I would like it to only say "incorrect answer, please try again".

Is there any way to do this?

Tried to use something like `alert =`, but it doesn't meet my requirements.

There's `${parameters.numbers}` and `${parameters.answers}` in the code because I am using `lab.js` for the looping. They just mean every time the number in the equation and the answer would change. For example, for the first loop `${parameters.numbers}` is 200, and the corresponding answer `${parameters.answers}` is 194. `lab.js` would take care of converting these two parameters to actual numbers for each loop of the form.

```
<form>
  <label for="algebra">${parameters.numbers} - 6 = ?</label><br>
  <input name="algebra" type="number" id="algebra" required="" max="${parameters.answers}" min="${parameters.answers}"><br>

  <button type="submit">OK</button>
</form>
```

I try to avoid a dramatic alert dialogue for this, just a non-intrusive message like the default style would be good. If you want to recreate the default "values must be greater than or equal to ..." message, just replace the parameters like this would be good:

```
<form>
  <label for="algebra">200 - 6 = ?</label><br>
  <input name="algebra" type="number" id="algebra" required="" max="194" min="194"><br>

  <button type="submit">OK</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't set the correct answer with min & max. Instead, just call a javascript function by giving your button tag an `onClick` to evaluate if the user's answer is correct.

```
   <button onclick="evaluateAnswer('.algebra');" class="submitBtn" >OK</button>
```

Then your javascript should look something like this:

```
    function evaluateAnswer(cssClass){
        var usersAnswer = $(cssClass).val();
        var actualCorrectAnswer = 100;

        if(usersAnswer == actualCorrectAnswer){
          //Do something to proceed

        }else{
          alert('Sorry, your answer is incorrect');
        }

    }
```

Also, I just noticed that you did not want to alert as-in a javascript alert. What you could do is style your message and give it a css class that has the property `display:none`. Then when you want to show the message when user enters the wrong answer, you can use javascript to remove the class, and also use javascript to add the class back when user enters correct answer.

**Edit**
You should maybe store your correct answers in a database, evaluate it's correctness serverside, and use Ajax to display the message to prevent users from being able to right-click -> view source and look at the answers in your client-side code

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, `lab.js` is kind of limited in terms of the full capacity of web development, since it's more of a research tool to design psychological experiments and surveys. At last I had to set up an invisible html element to store the actual answer and use javascript to validate the submission.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @ElroyJetson that putting the answer inside the tag is not a good idea, but I focused this answer on the way you can set and unset the error message.

I used jQuery, but this can also be done with plain javascript.

The idea is to group the `input` tag with a `span` tag (here inside the `div` with class `input-field`).

When the value changes or when the form is submitted (in this case when the value changes), you remove any previous error message from the span tag, and then perform the validation. If there is an error you set it in the span tag.

In this way the error message will show below the input element.

To try it fill in an answer and click outside of the input box.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".input-field").change(function(){
      let $inputField = $(this);
      let $input = $inputField.find("input");
      let $errorMsg = $inputField.find("span.err-msg");
      let max = Number($input.data("max"));
      let min = Number($input.data("min"));
      $errorMsg.text("");
      let v = Number($input.val());
      if(v < min || v > max){
        $errorMsg.text("Invalid answer");
      }
  });
});
```

```css
.err-msg{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="input-field">
    <label for="algebra">200 - 6 = ?</label><br>
    <input name="algebra" type="number" id="algebra" required="" data-max="194" data-min="194"><br>
    <span class="err-msg"></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is like this. There is invisible html elements which stores the correct answer, and the `js` script validates if the input is correct. Again, the ${} parts represents variables that change in each loop.

`html` part

```
<main class="content-horizontal-center content-vertical-center">
  <form name="mathEvaluation">
    <label for="algebra">${parameters.numbers} - 6 = ?</label><br>
    <input name="answer" type="number" id="answer" required="" size="3"><br>
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
    <input type="hidden" id="hidenAnswer" value=${parameters.answers} />
  </form>
</main>
```

`js` part

```
this.options.validator = function(data) {
  if(mathEvaluation.answer.value == mathEvaluation.hidenAnswer.value){
    return true
      } else {
        alert("Please enter the correct number.")
        }
}
```